# Order by with left join not using indexes and very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following two queries.Query 1 is fast since it uses indexes(uses nested loop join) and Query 2 uses hash join and it is slower.

Query 1 does order by on table 1 column and Query 2 does order by using table 2 column.

**Query 1**

```
learning=# explain analyze
select *
from users left join
     access_logs
     on users.userid = access_logs.userid
order by users.userid
limit 10 offset 90;


                                                    QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=14.00..15.46 rows=10 width=104) (actual time=1.330..1.504 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.85..291532.97 rows=1995958 width=104) (actual time=0.037..1.482 rows=100 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: (users.userid = access_logs.userid)
         ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.43..151132.75 rows=1995958 width=76) (actual time=0.018..1.135 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using access_logs_userid_idx on access_logs  (cost=0.43..110471.45 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=0.012..0.198 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.469 ms
 Execution time: 1.569 ms
```

**Query 2**

```
learning=# explain analyze
select *
from users left join
     access_logs
     on users.userid = access_logs.userid
order by access_logs.userid
limit 10 offset 90;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=293584.20..293584.23 rows=10 width=104) (actual time=3821.432..3821.439 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=293583.98..298573.87 rows=1995958 width=104) (actual time=3821.391..3821.415 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: access_logs.userid
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 51kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=73231.06..217299.90 rows=1995958 width=104) (actual time=539.859..3168.754 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (users.userid = access_logs.userid)
               ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..44814.58 rows=1995958 width=76) (actual time=0.009..443.260 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=34636.58..34636.58 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=539.112..539.112 rows=1995958 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 58532kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on access_logs  (cost=0.00..34636.58 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=0.006..170.061 rows=1995958 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.480 ms
 Execution time: 3832.245 ms
```

**Questions**

- The second query is slow since the sorting is done before the join as in the plan.
- Why does the sort in the second table not use the index? There is a plan below with just the sort.

**Query** - explain analyze select * from access_logs order by userid limit 10 offset 90;

**Plan**

```
 Limit  (cost=5.41..5.96 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.199..0.218 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using access_logs_userid_idx on access_logs  (cost=0.43..110471.45 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=0.029..0.201 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.120 ms
 Execution time: 0.252 ms
```

**Edit 1**:

My goal is not to compare both queries, in fact I want the result as in query 2,I just provided query 1 so that I can understand in comparison.

The order by is not limited to the join column, the user can also do order by another column in table 2, plans are below.

```
learning=# explain analyze select * from users left join access_logs on users.userid=access_logs.userid order by access_logs.last_login limit 10;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=260431.83..260431.86 rows=10 width=104) (actual time=3846.625..3846.627 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=260431.83..265421.73 rows=1995958 width=104) (actual time=3846.623..3846.623 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: access_logs.last_login
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=73231.06..217299.90 rows=1995958 width=104) (actual time=567.104..3174.818 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (users.userid = access_logs.userid)
               ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..44814.58 rows=1995958 width=76) (actual time=0.007..443.364 rows=1995958 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=34636.58..34636.58 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=566.814..566.814 rows=1995958 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 262144  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 58532kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on access_logs  (cost=0.00..34636.58 rows=1995958 width=28) (actual time=0.004..169.137 rows=1995958 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.490 ms
 Execution time: 3857.171 ms
```

Comment: Both queries return a totally different result set. The outer joins probably returns NULLs in `access_logs.userid` and you ORDER by this column.

Comment: dnoeth is right. And if `access_log.userid` does not contain `null` values, then ordering by `users.userid` is the same as ordering by `access_log.userid` (because they are identical because it's the join column).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I have made an edit above,sorry for not telling it in the first place

Comment: Try to move the "limited" access_log query into a CTE: http://pasted.co/7b5cef2e

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I am not able to fully understand the CTE that you provided.I am able to understand the first with section i.e selecting from access_logs as al, but what is "limited" here ?

Comment: `access_logs.last_login` is a strange column name for a log table (which probably has an 1:N association with `users`, and should be part of a natural key)

Comment: `limited` is the name of the CTE.

Comment: @joop : These are dummy tables, I made them myself for understanding.And the relationship is not 1:N it is 1:1 with a userid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : The CTE is somewhat better, it takes 2 Seconds now, but still there is a sort step involved which does not use the index.Maybe I am doing it wrong

Comment: Next time please add the DDL to your question. (a `xxx_logs` table strongly indicates a 1:N association)

Comment: @Greedy Coder, how did you get the log informations of the "query plan"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort in the second query would not use index because the index is not guaranteed to have all the values being sorted. If there are some records in `users` not matched by `access_logs` then `Left Join` would generate `null` values referenced in query as `access_logs.userid` but not actually present in `access_logs` and thus not covered by the index.

The workaround can be to create a default initial record in `access_log` for each user and use `Inner Join`.

Comment: So if that is the case then an index would not be possible for this query ?